# Draw graphics on screen

Tags: vb.net, graphics

I am using Visual Basic.Net and am drawing graphics on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(New IntPtr(0))
gr.DrawString("text on screen", 
               New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 25, 
               FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Red, 50, 50)
End Sub
```

In the above code, text is drawn on the screen. My question is this: How can I remove the text that is drawn to screen? I see that there is a .Clear method, however, this 'Clears the entire drawing surface and fills it with the specified background color', rather than just removing the drawn text.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am wanting to develop a subliminal message application that will show messages on screen while the user is using other applications. Would the transparent form be the best way to do this?

Comment: This is not an appropriate way to paint.  Whatever you draw can be erased at any random moment.  Having trouble restoring it is but another example of why you should not do this.  Create your own window.  It doesn't have to be visible, use the Form.TransparencyKey property.

Comment: Also, `IntPtr.Zero` is ***NOT*** how you get the desktop window handle.  See `GetDesktopWindow()`

Comment: `InvalidateRect()` might be suitable for clearing the drawn text.

Comment: All that said - @HansPassant is correct.  a new window with a transparencyKey or utilizing WS_EX_LAYERED, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and UpdateLayeredWindow()

Comment: You could always write the same text in the same place with the background color, if your background is a solid color.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code that works:

```
    Private WithEvents TextForm As New Form
Private Zipper As New FontFamily("Zipper")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With TextForm
        .BackColor = Color.DimGray
        .TransparencyKey = Color.DimGray
        .FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        .ShowInTaskbar = False
        .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        .Opacity = 0
        .Show(Me)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static showText As Boolean
    showText = Not showText
    If showText Then TextForm.Opacity = 0.99 Else TextForm.Opacity = 0
End Sub

Private Sub TextForm_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles TextForm.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawString("text on screen 12345", New Font(Zipper, 30, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, 50, 50)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take different bitmaps and draw each new thing in separate bitmaps and after merge new bitmap with old one. When you want to remove text reload old bitmap which is without text.
Search for drawing in new bitmaps and save drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Dim Graphics0 as Graphics = Graphics.fromHwnd(0) 'This is the desktop's graphics
Graphics0.DrawText("Test 1..2..3..",New Font(Arial,10),Brushes.Black,New Point(0,0))
```